# How to control your laughter in situation where you can't laugh openly?

Tags: personal-care

I have been facing problems when my boss always speaks something silly and I am in that situation where I can't react.

Comment: Coughing usually works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pain usually works.  Make sure your boss won't see it:

- Bite your tongue.
- Bite the inside of your cheek.
- Dig your thumbnail into the side of your finger.
- Pinch yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Open a little bit your mouth, Breathe through your nose and focus on your breathing. That should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Think of something really serious. Try to focus your mind on work or something else.